# change the directory and grab the xml file to parse certain data in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse specific XML file which is  located in sub directories of one directory. For some reason i am getting error saying file does not exists.  if the file does not exist it should move on to next sub directory.

HERE IS MY CODE

```
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use Data::Dumper;
        use XML::Simple;

        my @xmlsearch = map { chomp; $_ } `ls`;

        foreach my $directory (@xmlsearch) {
            print "$directory \n";
            chdir($directory) or die "Couldn't change to [$directory]: $!";
            my  @findResults = `find   -name education.xml`;

         foreach my $educationresults (@findResults){
            print $educationresults;
            my $parser = new XML::Simple;
            my $data = $parser->XMLin($educationresults);
            print Dumper($data);
            chdir('..');         
         }

        }

      ERROR
      music/gitar/education.xml
      File does not exist: ./music/gitar/education.xml
```

Comment: Why not [`use File::Find;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)?

Comment: Did you want to find `education.xml` files recursively, or only in those directories?

Comment: hello i just wanted find education.xml to one directory up. so main directory is music with lets say 10 subdirectories. example gitar, piano, drum. i want to search under only music/gitar or music/piano. i do not want to search under music/gitar/dir1/dir2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `chdir` the way you did makes the code IMO less readable. You can use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) for that:

```
use autodie;
use File::Find;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

sub findxml {
    my @found;

    opendir(DIR, '.');
    my @where = grep { -d && m#^[^.]+$# } readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);

    File::Find::find({wanted => sub {
        push @found, $File::Find::name if m#^education\.xml$#s && -f _;
    } }, @where);
    return @found;
}

foreach my $xml (findxml()){
    say $xml;
    print Dumper XMLin($xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself relying on backticks to execute shell commands, you should consider whether there is a proper perl way to do it. In this case, there is.

`ls` can be replaced with `<*>`, which is a simple glob. The line:

```
my @array = map { chomp; $_ } `ls`;
```

Is just a roundabout way of saying

```
chomp(my @array = `ls`);  #  chomp takes list arguments as well
```

But of course the proper way is

```
my @array = <*>;  # no chomp required
```

Now, the simple solution to all of this is simply to do

```
for my $xml (<*/education.xml>) { # find the xml files in dir 1 level up
```

Which will cover one level of directories, with no recursion. For full recursion, use `File::Find`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @list;
find( sub { push @list, $File::Find::name if /^education\.xml$/i; }, ".");

for (@list) {
    # do stuff
    # @list contains full path names of education.xml files found in subdirs
    # e.g. ./music/gitar/education.xml
}
```

You should note that changing directories is not required, and in my experience, not worth the trouble. Instead of doing:

```
chdir($somedir);
my $data = XMLin($somefile);
chdir("..");
```

Simply do:

```
my $data = XMLin("$somedir/$somefile");
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer it helped to search back to only one subdirectory. :)